# ggplot not working if I pass a dataframe as an element of a list

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
> ds
      domanda esito cella
22870   22870     B    36
22893   22893     R    25
16258   16258     P    12
14684   14684     P    15
12873   12873     B     5
12933   12933     B    33
12047   12047     R    44
22880   22880     B    39
11479   11479     P    33
20836   20836     B    38
```

If I do like that:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ds[-1] %>% 
  group_by(cella) %>%
  mutate(n =n()) %>%
  unique() %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x= cella, y=n, fill=esito)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') #, position='dodge'
```

it simply works. 
Now I want to create a pdf with three images.

So, the following code:

```
#------------------------------------------------+
myList <- list(ds,ds,ds)
myTitles <- c("title 1", "title 2", "title 3")
ds_k <- ds
pdf("RPB_som_separate.pdf",width=14)
  for(i in 1:length(myList)){
    ds_k <- myList[[i]]

    print(  
      ds_k[-1] %>% 
        group_by(cella) %>%
        mutate(n =n()) %>%
        unique() %>% 
        ggplot(., aes(x= cella, y=n, fill=esito)) + 
              geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
              ggtitle(myTitles[i])
    )

}
dev.off()
```

finally creates the pdf I wanted.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You used `g <- ggplot(.` instead it can be `%>% ggplot(., `

Comment: It worked! Thanks again.

Comment: I have changed slightly the question because the code does not let me to create a pdf file if I cannot use a function like print(g) where g <- ggplot(....). I tried putting all your code inside a print command but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: your code works, you just have to change a typo `ds_k <- myLista[[i]]` to `ds_k <- myList[[i]]`